# Calculate total when lower level table is amended in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Is there any clever trick for calculating totals when down stream tables are updated?  What I mean is... imagine you have 3 tables...

1) Orders - keyed on order id

2) OrderLines - keyed on order id and lineno, with part code and quantity

3) Parts - keyed on Partid, with cost and a STATUS flag

Now I have a SQL statement as follows:

    `SELECT 
       o.orderid,
       sum(p.[cost] * l.[quantity]) as totalcost
    from orders o
    inner join orderslines l on o.orderid = l.orderid
    inner join parts p on p.partid = l.partid
    where p.statusflag = 'U'
    group by o.orderid`

So I am looking for where a parts status is changed to "U" (for updated, or whatever).  This works, BUT only gives me the total for the updated parts.  I want the total for the entrire order (all lines and parts), but only for the orders where any part is updated.

Now I know I could create a where clause where orderno in list (and do another big join down the chain to get me the order numbers) - but wondered if there was an easier way in SQL?

For instance, imagine that instead of a 3 table structure there was 12 tables - that SQL would get very complex very fast.   I was wondering if there was a function I had missed, a KEYWORD prehaps, that says "now you have the orders, just recalculate everything for those orders"

This is on SQL Server 2016

Thanks

UPDATED: As requested, a test set of 3 tables and some sample data.   I would have expected/hoped for just orderid 3, with a value of 15.51 (2 lines for 2 products with a total of 15.51, even though only 1 would have been updated), and also order number 2 (for a total of 11), but NOT order 1 (as no parts in order 1 are updated)...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [OrderId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Orders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =     OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrdersLines](
    [OrderId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [lineid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PartId] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [quantity] [int] NULL,
    [statusflag] [varchar](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_OrdersLines] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OrderId] ASC,
    [lineid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =     OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parts](
    [PartId] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [cost] [float] NULL,
    [statusflag] [varchar](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Parts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PartId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderId], [StatusFlag]) VALUES (1, N'Y')
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderId], [StatusFlag]) VALUES (2, N'Y')
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderId], [StatusFlag]) VALUES (3, N'Y')
INSERT [dbo].[OrdersLines] ([OrderId], [lineid], [PartId], [quantity], [statusflag]) VALUES (1, 1, N'DOG', 1, N'Y')
INSERT [dbo].[OrdersLines] ([OrderId], [lineid], [PartId], [quantity], [statusflag]) VALUES (1, 2, N'CAT', 2, N'Y')
INSERT [dbo].[OrdersLines] ([OrderId], [lineid], [PartId], [quantity], [statusflag]) VALUES (2, 1, N'CAT', 3, N'Y')
INSERT [dbo].[OrdersLines] ([OrderId], [lineid], [PartId], [quantity], [statusflag]) VALUES (2, 2, N'FISH', 1, N'Y')
INSERT [dbo].[OrdersLines] ([OrderId], [lineid], [PartId], [quantity], [statusflag]) VALUES (2, 3, N'BEAR', 1, N'Y')
INSERT [dbo].[OrdersLines] ([OrderId], [lineid], [PartId], [quantity], [statusflag]) VALUES (3, 1, N'BEAR', 1, N'Y')
INSERT [dbo].[OrdersLines] ([OrderId], [lineid], [PartId], [quantity], [statusflag]) VALUES (3, 2, N'FRIMBLE', 1, N'Y')
INSERT [dbo].[Parts] ([PartId], [cost], [statusflag]) VALUES (N'BEAR',     4.4, N'U')
INSERT [dbo].[Parts] ([PartId], [cost], [statusflag]) VALUES (N'CAT', 1.1, N'Y')
INSERT [dbo].[Parts] ([PartId], [cost], [statusflag]) VALUES (N'DOG', 2.2, N'Y')
INSERT [dbo].[Parts] ([PartId], [cost], [statusflag]) VALUES (N'FISH', 3.3, N'Y')
INSERT [dbo].[Parts] ([PartId], [cost], [statusflag]) VALUES (N'FRIMBLE', 11.11, N'Y')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN p.statusflag = 'U' THEN 'X' END) > 0
```

to only include orders where at least one part has a status flag of U

```
SELECT o.orderid,
       sum(p.[cost] * l.[quantity]) AS totalcost
FROM   orders o
       INNER JOIN orderslines l
         ON o.orderid = l.orderid
       INNER JOIN parts p
         ON p.partid = l.partid
GROUP  BY o.orderid
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN p.statusflag = 'U' THEN 'X' END) > 0
```

In your example data this returns orders 2 and 3 as both are linked to `PartId` of `BEAR` which has this flag set.